# Does Java have built-in "reversed" SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

`SwingWorker` lets you prepare some data in a background `Thread` and then use it in EDT. I am looking for a utility that does the opposite: Prepare data in EDT, and then pass it to a background `Thread`.

If you're curious, the use case is saving state of a `JTable` to disk (column order, size, etc.). I need to talk to its model in EDT, but don't want to write to disk from this thread.

Something like:

```
void saveCurrentState(final Table table) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TableColumns state = dumpState(table);
            saveToDisk(table.getTableKey(), state);
        }
    });
}
```

`dumpState()` needs to run in EDT. `saveToDisk()` should NOT run in EDT. The whole thing is deliberately wrapped in `invokeLater()`, and I cannot replace it with `invokeAndWait()`.

Comment: What is that other thread doing? If it's a new thread, just give it the data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Get one using [`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) – or the other `newXXX()` methods, but that one should be okay for most uses.

That said, I believe this is something you can do with `SwingWorker` as well. Just prepare your data in the event handler *before* you create a `SwingWorker` – you're already on the EDT there. If you need to initiate this from a non-EDT thread, prepare the data using `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`, and then spin off another thread to do the writing (or do it in the same non-EDT thread you started with.)

`SwingWorker` and `ExecutorService` provide the same basic service – spin off some work into a background thread without having to manage its lifecycle explicitly. `SwingWorker` has a convenient method of communicating with the EDT without using `invokeLater()` all over the place that you don't need to use, and `ExecutorService` supports *futures* as a more general (non-Swing-specific) way of communicating with asynchronous task. For a fire-and-forget use case as yours both are fine.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I went for in the end. Now if only Java had closures... :-)

Comment: At the rate the lambda JSR is proceeding, Java should have closures no later than 2020!